# Как получить результат из разных баз данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Доброго всем времени суток. 
Нужно получить результат выборки из разных баз данных. Мне нужно что бы во вью передались оба результата. По отдельности у меня это выходит. Как это можно реализовать и передать во View?

```
public ViewResult AddCashToBar(int barId)
        {
            var cashToBar = barsRep.Bars
                .Select(e => new Bar { id = e.id, nameBars = e.nameBars})
                .Where(a => a.id == barId);    
            return (cashToBar);
        }

public ViewResult CashboxList()
        {
            var list = repository.ObjPos
                .Select(e => new Cash { id = e.id, name = e.name })
                .ToList();
            return View(list);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public class CachVM
{
    public int? CashToBar { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cash> List { get; set; }
}

public ViewResult CashboxList(int barId)
{
    CashVM result = new CashVM();

    result.List = repository.ObjPos
                  .Select(e => new Cash { id = e.id, name = e.name })
                  .ToList();

    resiult.CashToBar = barsRep.Bars
                        .Select(e => new Bar { id = e.id, nameBars = e.nameBars})
                        .Where(a => a.id == barId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    return View(result);
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам СПАСИБО! Все заработало.